# PyQt - displaying widget on top of widget

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, qwidget

I'm making an application that shows a map of an area and I'm trying to draw nodes on top of it which can represent information.

I made it all work, but did so simply by making one custom widget which I showed and printing everything again and again everytime information changed. Also I couldn't 'connect' the nodes to listeners, because they were just images in the original widget.

This made me want to reform my GUI and now I'm trying to make every class a custom widget! But there's a problem, my MapNodes aren't showing up anymore.

I searched stackoverflow and found this helpful thread:
[How to set absolute position of the widgets in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329754/how-to-set-absolute-position-of-the-widgets-in-qt)

So I have to give my mapnodes a parent, and parent = the widget that is being shown (?)

Anyway, here is my throw at it, pasting the relevant code here. Hint at where stuff might go horrible wrong: all the inits

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(list())
mutexbranch = Lock()
mutexnode = Lock()

def exec():
    return app.exec_()

#Singleton Pattern: wanneer en object aan iets moet kunnen
#                   waar het inherent door de structuur niet aankon
#                   wordt dit via dit singleton opgelost
class GuiInternalCommunication:
    realmap = 0


class MapView(QtGui.QWidget, listener.Listener):
    def __init__(self, mapimagepath):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        listener.Listener.__init__(self)

        self.map = Map(self, mapimagepath)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.map)

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Population mapping')

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.map)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        resolution = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(20,20,550,800)
        self.show()



######################################################################

class Map(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, mapimagepath):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

        #coordinaten hoeken NE en SW voor kaart in map graphics van SKO 
        self.realmap = RealMap( 
            mapimagepath,
            (51.0442, 3.7268), 
            (51.0405, 3.7242),
            550, 
            800)
        GuiInternalCommunication.realmap = self.realmap

        self.needsupdate = True
        self.timelabel = 0

        parent.setGeometry(0,0,self.realmap.width, self.realmap.height)

        self.mapNodes = {}
        self.mapBranches = {}

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        rect = self.contentsRect()

        #teken achtergrond
        self.realmap.drawRealMap(painter)

        #teken branches
        mutexbranch.acquire()
        try:
            for branch, mapBranch in self.mapBranches.items():
                mapBranch.drawMapBranch(painter)
        finally:
            mutexbranch.release()           



######################################################################

class RealMap(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, path, coordRightTop, coordLeftBot, width, height, pixpermet = 2.6):
        super(RealMap, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.mapimage = QtGui.QImage(self.path)
        self.coordLeftBot = coordLeftBot
        self.coordRightTop = coordRightTop

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.realdim = self.calcRealDim()

        self.pixpermet = pixpermet

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        self.drawRealMap(self, painter)
        painter.end()

    def drawRealMap(self, painter):
        painter.drawImage(0,0,self.mapimage)


######################################################################

class MapNode(QtGui.QWidget):
    dangertocolor = {"normal":"graphics//gradients//green.png",
                    "elevated":"graphics//gradients//orange.png",
                    "danger":"graphics//gradients//red.png"}

    gradimage = {"normal":QtGui.QImage(dangertocolor["normal"]),
                    "elevated":QtGui.QImage(dangertocolor["elevated"]),
                    "danger":QtGui.QImage(dangertocolor["danger"])}
    btimage = QtGui.QImage("graphics//BT-icon.png")

    def __init__(self, scanner, x, y, danger = 0, parent = None):
        # MapNode erft over van QWidget
        super(MapNode, self).__init__()
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.scanner = scanner
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.danger = 'normal'
        self.calcDanger(danger)

        self.grads = {}
        self.grad = QtGui.QImage(MapNode.dangertocolor[self.danger])


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        self.drawMapNode(painter)
        painter.end()

    def drawMapNode(self, painter):
        realmap = GuiInternalCommunication.realmap
        radiusm = self.scanner.range
        radiusp = radiusm*realmap.pixpermet
        factor = radiusp/200        # basis grootte gradiënten is 200 pixels.

        grad = MapNode.gradimage[self.danger]
        grad = grad.scaled(grad.size().width()*factor, grad.size().height()*factor)

        painter.drawImage(self.x-100*factor,self.y-100*factor, grad)
        painter.drawImage(self.x-10, self.y-10,MapNode.btimage)
        painter.drawText(self.x-15, self.y+20, str(self.scanner.sensorid) + '-' + str(self.scanner.name))


######################################################################

class MapBranch:
    branchpens = {"normal": QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
                "elevated": QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 51, 0), 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine), #mandarine orange hex is 255-165-0 
                "danger": QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 3, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)}

    def __init__(self, branch, mapnode1, mapnode2, danger = 0):
        self.mapnode1 = mapnode1
        self.mapnode2 = mapnode2
        self.branch = branch
        self.danger = danger

        self.calcDanger(danger)

    def drawMapBranch(self, painter):
        painter.setPen(MapBranch.branchpens[self.danger])
        painter.drawLine(self.mapnode1.x, 
                        self.mapnode1.y,
                        self.mapnode2.x,
                        self.mapnode2.y)
```

EDIT - I forgot to add the code that adds the nodes. So after an event comes in the node needs to be created, this method fires creating the node:

```
def addNode(self, scanner):
    mutexnode.acquire()
    try:
        coord = self.realmap.convertLatLon2Pix((scanner.latitude, scanner.longitude))
        self.mapNodes[scanner.sensorid] = MapNode(scanner, coord[0], coord[1], parent = self)
        self.mapNodes[scanner.sensorid].move(coord[0],coord[1])
        #self.mapNodes[scanner.sensorid].show()
    finally:
        mutexnode.release()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem classes for your map instead of normal QWidget classes, since they are made exactly for the purpose of displaying a large number of graphical items:

- QGraphicsScene http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html
- QGraphicsItem: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem-members.html

From the documentation:

> The QGraphicsScene class provides a surface for managing a large number of 2D graphical items.
>
> The class serves as a container for QGraphicsItems. It is used together with QGraphicsView for visualizing graphical items, such as lines, rectangles, text, or even custom items, on a 2D surface. QGraphicsScene is part of the Graphics View Framework.
>
> QGraphicsScene also provides functionality that lets you efficiently determine both the location of items, and for determining what items are visible within an arbitrary area on the scene. With the QGraphicsView widget, you can either visualize the whole scene, or zoom in and view only parts of the scene.

You can also embed widgets derived from QWidget in the scene, which should allow you to display practically any kind of information. As a bonus, you will get layering, fast transformations and ready-to-use handling of mouse interactions, which should be quite useful for realizing an interactive map.

Comment: The above links are outdated

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, I fixed them!