# PyQt absolute position of QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QDialog` which has a layout, in this layout there are multiple `QWidgets`. Now I have a button, if the user presses this button I want to display a "tooltip" which displays some more information. This "tooltip" has to contain a layout.

For this I wanted to use a `QWidget` with an absolute position. When I put together the code mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329754/5934316) the solution does not work for me. I have also tried to use the `QtWidget.raise_()` function but the `QWidget` is not being displayed.

I stripped down my code to the following example:

```
# creating content
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
for i in range(0, 10):
    layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("line {} - bla bla bla bla bla bla".format(i)))

widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
widget.setLayout(layout)    

# creating dialog and apply the layout
dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
dialog.setLayout(layout)

# creating the absolute positioned widget
absolute_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
absolute_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Absolute positioned QWidget"))
absolute_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("With some widgets in itself"))
absolute_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("With some widgets in itself"))
absolute_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("With some widgets in itself"))

absolute = QtWidgets.QWidget(dialog)
absolute.setLayout(absolute_layout)

# show the absolute widget and move it
absolute.show()
absolute.move(10, 10)
absolute.raise_()

dialog.show()
```

The dialog is shown correctly with the content in the `layout` but the `absolute` is not being shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is really no point in using widgets for such a trivial task as this. A tooltip can render html, so just use a `<table>` for laying out the text.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, I know that. The code written above is obviously not my real code. As I wrote I need to use a `QLayout` object in this "tooltip", this layout contains some custom widgets. With using html I cannot achieve the result I want to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @G.M. I found out that the solution is really easy:

```
absolute = QtWidgets.QWidget()
absolute.setParent(dialog)
```

I was expecting that the [`QWidget::QWidget(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#QWidget) constructor is calling the `QWidget::setParent(QWidget * parent)` method internally (which is not true?).

Answer (score 1):

By using...

```
absolute = QtWidgets.QWidget(dialog)
```

you have made `absolute` a child of `dialog`.  Hence the geometry of `absolute` will always be governed to some extent by `dialog`.  If you want to be able to specify the absolute geometry of a widget use...

```
absolute = QtWidgets.QWidget()
```

Comment: But don't I *have* to make the `absolute` a child of `dialog`? If I call the `show()` method of a `QWidget` which does not have a child it will be shown as a new window.