# How to set GraphicsWindow position in PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, window, position, pyqtgraph, vispy

With VisPy library, one can set canvas position by doing:

```
from vispy import app    
canvas = app.Canvas(position=(0,0)) #Left top position
```

Is there a way to do the same with PyQtGraph library?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
win = pg.GraphicsWindow() #position?
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use [QWidget::move](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1) method. In my example :

```
win.move(pos_x, pos_y)
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329754/how-to-set-absolute-position-of-the-widgets-in-qt) gives further details.